# I got NullPointerException in a JSP file when im trying to create a matrix with a database in mysql

Tags: mysql, jsp, matrix, nullpointerexception, database-connection

im trying to create a matrix based on registers of a database named "foro", the problem is that im getting a nullPointerException i have tried everything, well here's the jsp code:

```
<%@page import="DB.MySqlConn"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <jsp:useBean id="link" class="DB.MySqlConn"/>
        <%@page session="true"%>
        <%
            String query="select * from consulta order by fecha";
            String [][]pub=null;
            pub=link.ConsultMat(query);
            for(int i=pub.length-1;i>=0;i++){
                out.println(pub[i][4]);
            }
        %>
```

and this is the class named "MySqlConn":

```
public class MySqlConn 
{
    public Statement stmt=null;
    public ResultSet rs=null;
    public Connection conn=null;
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd =null;
    boolean cont=true;

    public MySqlConn() 
    {
        cont=true;
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/foro?"
                            + "user=root&password=MyPass";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQL Exception: "+e.toString());
            cont=false;
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("Class Not Found Exception: "+e.toString());
            cont=false;
        }
    }
public String[][] ConsultMat(String query){
int n=0,m=0;
        int i,j;
        String[][]datos=null;
try{
            stmt =  conn.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            if(stmt.execute(query)){
                rs = stmt.getResultSet();
                rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                rs.last();
                n=rs.getRow();
                rs.first();
                m=rsmd.getColumnCount();
                datos = new String[n][m];
                for(i =0;i<n;i++){
                    for(j=0;j<m;j++){
                        try{
                            datos[i][j]=rs.getString(j + 1);
                        }catch(Exception e){}
                    }
                    try{
                        rs.next();
                    }catch(Exception e){}
                }
            }

        }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException: "+e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("SQLState: " + e.getSQLState());
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getErrorCode());  
        }
        return datos;      
    }
}
```

please help me !

Comment: Welcome to [so]!  Take a look at the [tour] and the [help].  Can you please edit your question to show the full error message?

Answer (score 0):

Change:

for(int i=pub.length-1;i>=0;i++){

to:

for(int i=pub.length-1;i>=0;i--){

you are iterating in a wrong direction.

Comment: ooo yes that was a problem too, but the exception is still there on the line where im trying to create the matrix:
pub=link.ConsultMat(query);